# Hide Previous div and toggle next div on click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a number of buttons in my html. Each button referring to a particular DIV. I want an easy way to hide the previously open DIV when another button is clicked. So far I have written a code in jquery, but I have a strange feeling that am putting in a lot of code into a simply achievable task. Is there a simpler way to do this than what I have tried to accomplish?

Here is what I have done so far.

My HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>   
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>                      
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="body">
            <input type="button" name="division1" value="div1" class="buttons" id="button1"/>
            <input type="button" name="division2" value="div2" class="buttons" id="button2"/>
            <input type="button" name="division3" value="div3" class="buttons" id="button3"/>
            <input type="button" name="division4" value="div4" class="buttons" id="button4"/>
            <input type="button" name="division5" value="div5" class="buttons" id="button5"/>
            <input type="button" name="division6" value="div6" class="buttons" id="button6"/>
            <div id="div1" class="divs"></div>
            <div id="div2" class="divs"></div>
            <div id="div3" class="divs"></div>
            <div id="div4" class="divs"></div>
            <div id="div5" class="divs"></div>
            <div id="div6" class="divs"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

My CSS:

```
            #body{
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;    
                background-color: #000;
            }
            .buttons{
                width: 10%;
                height: 5%;
                position: relative;
                left: 10%;
                cursor: pointer;
                z-index: 500;
            }
            .divs{
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: none;
            }
            #div1{
                background-color: #377D9F;
            }
            #div2{
                background-color: #02B0E6;
            }
            #div3{
                background-color: #4b9500;
            }
            #div4{
                background-color: #aaa;
            }
            #div5{
                background-color:#aa0000;
            }
            #div6{
                background-color: aquamarine;
            }
```

My Jquery:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {       
        $("#button1").click(function () {
              $('#div1').toggle(100);
                  $("#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5,#div6").hide();               
        });          
         $("#button2").click(function () {
            $("#div2").toggle(100);
            $("#div1,#div3,#div4,#div5,#div6").hide();    
        });
         $("#button3").click(function () {
            $("#div3").toggle(100);
            $("#div1,#div2,#div4,#div5,#div6").hide();    
        });
         $("#button4").click(function () {
            $("#div4").toggle(100);
            $("#div1,#div2,#div3,#div5,#div6").hide();    
        });
         $("#button5").click(function () {
            $("#div5").toggle(100);
            $("#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div6").hide();    
        });
         $("#button6").click(function () {
            $("#div6").toggle(100);
            $("#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5").hide();    
        });
    });
```

I kind of have around 50 DIV's in my html like the above ones. And I think using the above JQUERY is a waste of coding lines. I know there will be a better way to do this. My code seems to work well, but is there any way in jquery to just hide the previous DIV, no matter which button user clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with this sentence *I kind of have around 50 DIV's in my html like the above ones*

This would be a lot more clean as well as convenient if you use a `select` tag, instead of using `button` to show and hide each `div`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G98tG/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="show_divs">
    <option>Select to show a div</option>
    <option value="1">Show 1</option>
    <option value="2">Show 1</option>
</select>

<div class="parent">
    <div id="show1">This is the first div</div>
    <div id="show2">This is the second div</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#show_divs').change(function() { //onChange execute the function
    var showDiv = $(this).val(); //Store the value in the variable
    $('div.parent > div').hide(); //Hide all the div nested inside .parent
    $('#show' + showDiv ).show(); //Fetch the value of option tag, concatenate it with the id and show the relevant div
});
```

**CSS**

```
div.parent > div {
    display: none; /* Hide initially */
}
```

If you want to avoid using id's, you can also create your custom attribute, like `data-show="1"` and `data-show="2"` so on...

Comment: @alien thanks for your help .... i hope the same can be achieved using li with href attribute?

Comment: @Vicky yes you can, but as I told you, 50 buttons are something not good as far as UI is concerned, so I provided you some better thing, which will also save you some markup, as well as it's a neat way to go

Comment: Bro i tried what you said and kind of its not working as i want it to ... if i click the previous link its not showing the div related to that here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5g6XR/) please help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44137/discussion-between-vicky-and-mr-alien)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".buttons").click(function () {
            var divname= this.value;
              $("#"+divname).slideToggle().siblings('.divs').hide("slow");
            });
 });
```

Comment: @SajadLfc its working but the thing is all the toggles come from top to bottom ... it slides down i mean .... but my toggles should start from the left top corner and fill the screen thanks for your reply....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".divs").hide();

    $(".buttons").click(function() {
        $(".divs").hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/88mt9/1/)

Comment: Thanks a million tons ... U made my life much easier ... and saved me from tons of LOC .....

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button"  value="div1" class="buttons" id="button1" />
<input type="button"  value="div2" class="buttons" id="button2" />
<input type="button"  value="div3" class="buttons" id="button3" />
<input type="button"  value="div4" class="buttons" id="button4" />
<input type="button"  value="div5" class="buttons" id="button5" />
<input type="button"  value="div6" class="buttons" id="button6" />
<div id="div1" class="divs">div1</div>
<div id="div2" class="divs">div2</div>
<div id="div3" class="divs">div3</div>
<div id="div4" class="divs">div4</div>
<div id="div5" class="divs">div5</div>
<div id="div6" class="divs">div6</div>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
    $('.divs').hide();
    $('#div'+$(this).attr('id').replace('button','')).toggle(100);
      })

  })
</script>
```